# Run Arduino on USB and at the same time BreadBoard on higher voltage?

Tags: power, voltage-level, usb, battery

I am trying to design a bicycle LED lighting system, and for that I bought an Arduino yesterday (so very beginner with Arduino).

My final system will operate at 6V, so I plan to put everything on a breadbord and tune everything (blinking times, resistor values, etc.) and for that I want to keep my Arduino plugged to USB during development.

So my question is:

How should I connect USB-powered Arduino to a higher-voltage-powered breadbord (between 6 and 12V) safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as far as i understood the problem, the system or whatever you call is will run on what ever power as long that power is not fed to the arduino that will not be a problem, just connect the two grounds together and power the arduino through the computer and connect the pins to the system accordingly. i think this will solve thus the trivial problem.

Comment: You're right. After I figured it out (some days ago already), I got a little surprised no one pointed it out sooner. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you intend to run both supplies simultaneously, there's no problem. Your ~ 6v input will need to be stepped down and regulated to 5v, and the USB provides a regulated 5v, so the system shouldn't care which one you are using.

If you need to run your system off the 6v during development and need USB communication, I'd suggest using a USB-to-TTL-Serial cable such as this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718. Connect its Tx & Rx pins to your Arduino's (Uno?) pins 1 and 0, respectively, and it's ground pin to the ground rail served by your battery supply.

Typical regulators will need more headroom above their output voltage to give you a steady, regulated output, and this includes the 5v regulators on Arduino boards which usually specify 7-12v at the Vin (unregulated) input. A 6v battery won't meet this spec so you'd need a buck/boost regulator that could provide a regulated 5v from "0+" to 6v input. Or you might move your system to a bare AtMega328p with a lower clock speed (see the data sheet for max clock speed vs. Vcc), and run it at 3v (for example) which would give a simpler regulator more headroom from its 6v input.

Comment: I think you will find that: USB powerable Arduinos, by definition, operate from 5V. This is usually accomplished by using a 3V3 system and an LDO regulator with sub 1 V drop - or direct operation of a nominal 5V system on the USB voltages with a switched FET and perhaps slightly under 5V processor operation.

Comment: I tink I might haven't made myself clear. What I would like is to power only the breadboard with, say 6V from a battery, or from wall wart, and connect _only output pins_ from Arduino to the breadboard. This, in the example I gave with transistors, the transistors' collectors and their load would be polarized by the wall wart, the transistor bases would be connected to Arduino outputs, and everything would be grounded together (PC, Arduino and BreadBoard). Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. In fact, the PC needs no connection to the rest of your system beyond what the USB itself provides.

Answer (score 0):

Datasheet can be found here: http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx?tab=parameters

From this, the absolute rated voltage on the ATMega (aka, the chip at the heart of the Arduino) is 6V.  Above that... above that you risk magic smoke.  But you can just, *maybe* get away with running your whole system on 6V.

Important point - do not rely on using 4 AA batteries for this.  Regulate your 6Vish to *exactly* 6V.  Just remember that this is at the extreme limit of the spec.  If you try this, before you start repeat to yourself "I have just voided my warranty.  It is now my fault when it dies."

Alternatively, why are you so wedded to 6V?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am "wedded" to 6V because a lot (all?) of bike accessories are expected to run at 6V, and this include lights which would be an important part of my system. Since these lights nowadays use LEDs instead of bulb lamps, they are quite sensitive to voltage drops (some won't even turn on at 5V), so I'll stick to what's common practice for the sake of modularity and "swappability" between sub-systems. By the way, I ended up using an LM2940 low-dropout regulator, which successfully regulates 6V to 5V, or so it seems (I have just tested it quickly once)